# Sequelize Validar Email unico

Tags: nodejs, validación, sequelize

quiero validar que un Email sea único antes de guardar en la base de datos, y funciona, lo que no puedo es personalizar en mensaje. mi código es el siguiente:

```
email : {
    type       : Sequelize.STRING(40),
    allowNull  : false,
    unique: {    
        args: true,    
        msg: 'Correo ya está registrado en la base de datos',
    },
    validate:{
        isEmail:{
            msg: 'Agrega un correo válido'
        },
        notEmpty:{
            msg:'Favor ingrese un correo electronico'
        }
    }
}
```

Trate con la solución que encontré aquí, pero ya no funciona:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356856/sequelize-js-custom-validator-check-for-unique-username-password

Agradezco su ayuda. Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pusiste está bien, solo necesitas quitar el args

```js
email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
            msg: 'El email necesita ser unico'
        },
        validate: {
            isEmail: {
                msg: 'Email no valido'
            },
            notEmpty: {
                msg: 'Ingrese un email'
            }
        }
    }
```

Al momento de atrapar el error solo usas el error.message y vendrá el mensaje personalizado

Comment: Hola rock.. Sí, probé también esto y no funciono, no se que más puedo hacer, creo que mi única opción será pasarme a una versión anterior de Sequelize.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no te funciono? yo lo acabo de probar con la versión más nueva

Comment: Pues yo estoy la versión de Sequelize 5.21.5, y aunque tengo el código como hemos puesto anteriormente, siempre me lanza el mensaje default  **usuarios.usuarios_email_unique must be unique**